# Value of index + 1

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm looking to add some functionality to a spreadsheet that does the following.

I would like to run a Vlookup that looks for a match with another cell, if it finds a match in I20, I would like to return the value of I21. It will always have to return the value with the cell directly below it. Is there a way for me to do this?

I do not want to hard code, since the values in the vlookup maybe different, but it will always need the value directly below the match.

Comment: `=INDEX(I:I,MATCH("something",I:I,0)+1)`

Comment: That definitely works, is there a way that I can make it only do that if there is a match? I have an error whenever there is not a matching "something". I have something else subtracting from this. So it's a value - that formula, only if there is a match in the index.

Comment: you can try: `=IFERROR(INDEX(I:I,MATCH("something",I:I,0)+1),"there is no match")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you can use

```
=INDEX(I:I,MATCH("something",I:I,0)+1)
```

`Index/Match` is pretty similar to `Vlookup`, you can read more [here](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/).

Also for error hadling you can use:

1) for Excel 2007 and later:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(I:I,MATCH("something",I:I,0)+1),"there is no match")
```

2) for Excel 2003:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(I:I,MATCH("something",I:I,0)+1)),"there is no match",INDEX(I:I,MATCH("something",I:I,0)+1))
```

Comment: You've helped me tremendously, my friend. Could you provide one last tip for this situation? :) When my cell is blank, I get an error. Here's my complete formula: =IF($I7=$E7,$E8+$I8,$I8)-IFERROR(INDEX($I$23:$I$35,MATCH($I7,$I$23:$I$35,0)+1),"0")  If the cell is blank, I get an error though. I tried ISERROR there too, but I think my syntax was off.

Comment: it's because you're trying to substract string `"0"`, try to replcase `"‌​0")` to `0)` like this: `=IF($I7=$E7,$E8+$I8,$I8)-IFERROR(INDEX($I$23:$I$35,MATCH($I7,$I$23:$I$35,0)+1),0)`. Also make sure that your `index/match` always returns _number_ rather than text